# get values before today by predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a Word of a Day app. I store the date of the word with `NSSTRING` and all is working fine. But when i want to show all words in the database, which date is less than `[NSDate date]` - which means today, it doesn't sort it well. I'm using NSpredicate to do that. How to make it work?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"date <= %@", [NSDate date]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Even when i put the string from current date, it doesn't work. I mean the comparison is only work for current month, because the format is : 11.06.2014

Comment: how do you store the date? in `NSDate`? or in `NSString`? or what is that exactly: `11.06.2014`?

Comment: in NSString. 11 - day, 06 - month, 2014 - year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to store your date as NSDate or a timestamp in database and convert it to NSString only for display.

If you cannot change your database scheme you can create predicate with +predicateWithBlock method:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(YourManagetObj* obj, NSDictionary *bind){
    NSDate* objDate = ... //convert string to date with the same date formatter you used to convert date to string
    return [objDate earlierDate:[NSDate date]] == objDate;
}];
```

Note also that with your scheme you'll have to use custom predicate that converts stored string to NSDate for sorting your objects by date.

Comment: seems like there is a mistake: return [objDate earlierDate:[NSDate date]] == referenceDate;

Comment: @user3336098, right copypaste error. sorry, corrected that